# Kile: ps to pdf finished with exit code 1

Tags: kile, ps2pdf

I am using Kile. While processing the tex:

DVI to PDF is working fine **but** PS to PDF showing error "ps to pdf finished with exit code 1" and PDF file is only showing first page of the documents.

Any suggestion to overcome this problem!! Thanks.